# Spring cloud stream rabbitmq specify topics in the consumer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to send messages with different topics and then configure the consumer on the topics it wants to listen to.

My idea is to use a single destination "domainMessage" and use custom partition strategy. I have an enum and I'm just using that value as the partitionKey and the partitionStrategy will just return the key(Assume that the key will always be equal to partition count at producer side).

Will this work? If so, I'm not sure how to configure the consumer.

My producer has the below application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=domainMessages
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-key-extractor-class=publisher.partitionstrategy.PartitionKeyExtractorImpl
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-selector-class=publisher.partitionstrategy.PartitionSelectorStrategyImpl
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-count=3
```

My PartitionKeyExtractorImpl looks like

```
@Override
    public Object extractKey(Message<?> message) {
        DomainMessage payload = (DomainMessage) message.getPayload();
        return payload.getType();
    }
```

My PartitionStrategyImpl looks like

```
@Override
    public int selectPartition(Object key, int partitionCount) {
        return (int)key;
    }
```

My Consumer application.properties looks like

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=domainMessage
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=group01
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.durable-subscription=true
```

Let's say `payload.getType()` can return values between 1-3. How can I configure the consumer to only listen to messages which had partitionKey as 1 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring cloud stream is very opinionated about declaring queues and exchanges.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=domainMessage
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=group01
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.durable-subscription=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.instance-index=0
```

(notice the instance-index)

This will bind `domainMessage.group01-0` to exchange `domainMessage` with routing key `domainMessage-0`.

If you wish to consume multiple partitions in a single instance, simply doing

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=domainMessage-0,domainMessage-1
```

(and deleting the `instance-index` and `partitioned=true`) won't work because it will bind each queue to the corresponding exchange (e.g. `domainMessage-0` with routing key `#`).

One solution would be to do this, but manually add an exchange-to-exchange binding to bind each consumer exchange (`domainMessage-n`) to the upstream exchange (`domainMessage`) with appropriate routing keys.

There is currently no way to automatically consume from more than one partition in a single `instance-index`.

Comment: Will this feature be supported in future? Just curious

Comment: It's not something that has come up before; usually people set up their partitioning and key selection to drive messages to a single partition - i.e. in your case, send keys 0 and 1 to partition 0. You could try opening a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues) with the suggestion.

Comment: Opened it
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/648